# Atom Remote Edit no longer displaying open files

Tags: ftp, atom-editor

Have been using Remote Edit package for a while without incident. Suddenly, I'm unable to view open files. I verified that opening local file works fine.

When I try to open a file from the server, dialogue goes through to completion "Successfully read remote file", just doesn't show it in the editor. I verified that the files aren't empty.

Tried to uninstall, re-install remote edit to no avail.

Using Atom v1.2.4 and remote edit v1.8.22

Comment: try asking it here https://github.com/sveale/remote-edit/issues/25